# Не запускается браузер селенд

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

вот код

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\chromedriver.exe");// "C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\chromedriver.exe");
       System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
       open("http://google.com");
```

код ошибки

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext
    at com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.<clinit>(SelenideDriver.java:31)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.lambda$getSelenideDriver$0(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.getSelenideDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:62)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getSelenideDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:100)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:40)
    at TestAll.Selend.main(Selend.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, у вас в classpath не хватает зависимости (которая должна содержать класс org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext).

Comment: `PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.LazyDriver getAndCheckWebDriver INFO: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1 - let's create a new webdriver Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverBinaryManager.isSystemPropertySet(WebDriverBinaryManager.java:55) at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverBinaryManager.setupChrome(WebDriverBinaryManager.java:19) at ` что эта ошибка может означать? я пытался на мавене делать

Comment: То же самое: у вас не хватает зависимости commons-lang-*.jar, в которой содержится класс org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.

Как именно вы пытались на мавене делать? Значит, как-то нверно объявили зависимости.

Comment: у меня есть сам мавен, я сделал мавен проект, и в pom.xml кинул http код, и все равно была та же ошибка

Comment: даже если я добавлял как библиотеку http все равно та же ошибка была в мавене

Comment: все заработало, я добавил эту библиотеку, и все работает.Не подскажите, как запустить конкретный браузер, если он у меня лежит в "C://User//Chrome.exe"